# I wanted to delete the user account on frontend using id on React using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, frontend

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Settings.module.css";
import axios from "axios";

const Settings = (e) => {
  const deleteAccount = async (info) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "authorizationToken"
      }
    };

    try {
      const result = await axios.delete(
        "http://localhost:7000/user/deleteAccount/:id",
```

```js
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Settings.module.css";
import axios from "axios";

const Settings = (e) => {
  const deleteAccount = async (info) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "authorizationToken"
      }
    };

    try {
      const result = await axios.delete(
        "http://localhost:7000/user/deleteAccount/:id",
        info,
        config
      );
      console.log(result);
      // setLoggedIn(true)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const userDelete = new userDelete(e.target);
    // const dataDelete= {
    //     _id:userDelete.remove("email")

    // }
  };
  try {
    deleteAccount();
  } catch (error) {}

  return (
    <div className={styles.containersetting}>
      {" "}
      Settings
      <div className={styles.deletecontainer}>
        <p>
          Are you sure you wanted to delete your account? If you choose to
          delete your account, you have to register again.
        </p>
        <button
          onClick={handleDeleteSubmit}
          className={styles.deletecontainer1}
        >
          Delete Account
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

```
        info,
        config
      );
      console.log(result);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const userDelete = new userDelete(e.target);
    

    
  };
  try {
    deleteAccount();
  } catch (error) {}

  return (
    <div className={styles.containersetting}>
      {" "}
      Settings
      <div className={styles.deletecontainer}>
        <p>
          Are you sure you wanted to delete your account? If you choose to
          delete your account, you have to register again.
        </p>
        <button
          onClick={handleDeleteSubmit}
          className={styles.deletecontainer1}
        >
          Delete Account
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
'
export default Settings;
```

=========================================
Here is my middleware
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const User = require("../Models/UserModel")

module.exports = async(request,response,next)=>{

const token = request.cookies.jwt
console.log('authenticate ',token);

```
if(!token){
    return response.status(400).json({msg: 'No Token authorization denied!!'})
}
try{
    const decode = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET)
    console.log('decode:', decode);
    request.id = decode.id
    const currentUser = await User.findById(decode.id)
    if(!currentUser){
        return response.status(400).json({msg: 'The User with the current token is no longer exist'})
    }
    request.id = currentUser.id
    console.log(request.user);
    next()
} catch(error){
    console.log(error);
    return response.status(400).json({msg: 'Token is not valid'})
}
```

}

======================

My error is authenticate undefined

Comment: So what is the actual problem, what is the result of your code, that you don't want?

Comment: If you have user's id info in props for Settings, use ``http://localhost:7000/user/deleteAccount/${e.id}`` inside backtiks as url to axios call.

Comment: I tried it , its not working